# What's the best way to add a robots.txt file to a SvelteKit project?

Tags: robots.txt, sveltekit

The official [SvelteKit docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/seo) on the topic of SEO, which mentions that a sitemap can be dynamically created using an endpoint. I could not find other documentation related to the robots.txt file, that can be used to reference the sitemap for web crawlers and SEO optimization.

I looked on other forums as well but could not find a solution. I created my robots.txt and included it at the root of my project `/` and in `/src` as well. When I search for the project file on `nazar-design.com/robots.txt` I am served with a 404 error message.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can place files in the directory named in your `kit.files.assets` configuration (which is the `/static` folder by default) to be served to users as-is.

In your case, placing the file at `/static/robots.txt` would yield the desired `nazar-design.com/robots.txt` URL.